# Creating a Neural Machine Translation basics

Tags: nlp, translation, machine-translation

I'm currently working on a project design where I will create a program/model to translate my native dialect to English, I'm asking is there any books or anything that can you recommend to me in creating my project.

Comment: Unfortunately, seeking recommendations on Stackoverflow is considered off-topic. You might consider other online communities, such as Reddit, instead.

Comment: Ask in https://reddit.com/r/machinetranslation or get this topic added to the Roadmap at https://machinetranslate.org

Comment: Looks like it's already on the roadmap: https://github.com/machinetranslate/machinetranslate.org/issues/96

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the NLP side of things there's this course: [Natural Language Processing with spaCy & Python - Course for Beginners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dIUTsFT2MeQ) and this older course: [Natural Language Processing (NLP) Tutorial with Python & NLTK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2vAabgKiuM) on [Free Code Camp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/), which is generally a good place to start. Their courses provide in depth explanations of concepts and provide good examples.

On the translation side of things, the [DeepL](https://www.deepl.com/en/translator) translator is easy to use in multiple languages and offers a free api. It also offers and incredibly easy to use [python library](https://github.com/DeepLcom/deepl-python) if that's the language you intend to use (which you should because python is the best out there for NLP).

I hope this helps, but [dennlinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3607203/dennlinger) is right - you shouldn't typically ask broad recommendation questions on StackOverflow!